# How to use a listview in android studio to search based off a return of a class function?

Tags: java, android

I am learning java and android studio and I am trying to make a menu with each food item being an individual class with a set of allergens either having a true or false value. I add the objects of each class into an ArrayList to display them using a list view. I have implemented a search bar that works correctly, however I am trying to modify the onTextChanged function so if for example the user types in "gluten" it will return all food items that DO NOT contain that allergen.

My code is as follows below, with the commented out sections being some testing I have attempted

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

//Test Classes for now will be added into a different file once working as intended.
 class Pad_Thai{
     public
     String name = "Pad Thai";
     boolean gluten = false;
     boolean shellfish = true;

        }
        class Fried_Rice{
     public
     String name = "Fried Rice";
            boolean gluten = true;
            boolean shellfish = true;
        }
class Beef_Broc{
    public
    String name = "Beef & Broc";
    boolean gluten = true;
    boolean shellfish = true;
}

//Testing Function to test if an object of a class has that allergen
//public class hasGluten {
 //    public boolean yes(boolean []arr) {
  //       for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 //            if (arr[i] == true) {
 //            }
 //        }
 //        return true;
  //   }

//}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theList);
        EditText theFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started.");

        //Creating Objects of the Specified classes
        Pad_Thai obj = new Pad_Thai();
        Beef_Broc obj2= new Beef_Broc();
        Fried_Rice obj3= new Fried_Rice();

        //array of an object of classes
        ArrayList<String> food = new ArrayList<>();
        //testing array
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

        food.add(obj.name);
        food.add(obj2.name);
        food.add(obj3.name);

        names.add("Orange Chicken");
        names.add("Pad Thai");
        names.add("Fried Rice");
        names.add("Beef and Broc");
        names.add("Special Tempora");


        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, food);
        adapter2 =  new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

       theFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           @Override
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
               (MainActivity.this).adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);

               //int textlength = charSequence.length();
               //ArrayList<food> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<food>();
               //for (food c : tempArrayList) {
              //     if (c.hasGluten() == false) {
              //         tempArrayList.add(c);
               //    }
               //}
               //mAdapter = new food(activity, tempArrayList);
               //lv.setAdapter(madapter);

               String gluten = "gluten";

               if (charSequence == gluten)
               {
                   (MainActivity.this).adapter2.getFilter();
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

           }
       });
    }
}
```